# Canvas editing mode in Umbraco 7. Where can we find it?

Tags: canvas, umbraco, umbraco7

Is there a website editing mode in Umbraco 7?

We were/are looking for a configuration setting to enable it, but we can't find anywhere.

Does anyone know whether it still exists and how to enable/access it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid to say that it would seem Canvas mode was one of the casualties of the upgrade to 7. It used to be that in the user settings against user types you could choose 'Edit in canvas' as a permission, but that is no longer present in v7

To be honest, Canvas was pretty flaky at the best of times and really wasn't the best way to handle inline editing, and with the UI rewrite is seems to have gone. Might be worth getting on Twitter and asking @Umbraco if they ever plan to bring it back

Answer (score 0):

If you mean inline editing on frontend, I suggest having a look at https://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/frontend-editing